# Using a PC to replace main wireless router

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have a media server and would like to re-purpose it as the main router machine with my wireless APs branching off it and so using it as default gateway, DHCP, Port forwarding etc.(probably with a network switch I assume).

I have a lot of experience with various linux distros but don't really know how to get started researching the networking aspect of this venture. So, my questions are:

1. Is this even a thing?
2. Am I asking this in the correct community?
3. Will I need a two network interfaces (ethernet ports) on the server - one for internet in (from the modem) and one for output to a switch?
4. Can I set this up to do everything that a Wireless router could do (including file server) ?

I would appreciate the feedback, I've had a hard time Googling this as I'm not too sure what I'm searching for, even?

Comment: I'm wondering whether there is a real need to do this when, as davidgo points out, you can flash an existing router with a custom firmware that does everything you want and it'll use less space and way less resources such as electricity... It seems very overkill for what you want to do. The managed switch idea is great because you can create VLANs but that's done through the switch GUI... You can then connect your wifi APs to the switch.

Comment: Not so much of a "real need", more of an experiment, really. I may very well be overkill in terms of functionality (the box I have it on 24/7 anyway so electricity and space are not concerns) but I'd like to have more versatility than a commercial Wireless AP can provide.

Comment: @BigChris I will look into the switch idea though. I thought they were just dump distribution units. Thanks.

Comment: ;) That's cool. Have a read up on the answer below (davidgo) as it contains pretty much everything you'll need. There are also some pre-fabricated Linux distributions that have many of these implemented and they gave their own web GUI already. An example is Endian Firewall but there are others. Endian had a free "community" version and paid-for versions with more functionality but not necessary for your experimenting :)

Comment: "Managed switches" allow you to do many things with the ports and traffic that a normal "dumb switch" simply can't.

Comment: There's always [Sophus UTM](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx?utm_source=Non-campaign&utm_medium=Cross-link&utm_campaign=CL-CorpBlog) Freeware to all intents & purposes, unless you need more than 50 seats. It's BYOC - 1 puter, 2 NICs. Full docs at http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/documentation/sophos-utm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this is a thing.
2. No you are asking the wrong community - maybe Superuser may be more appropriate.
3. Network Interfaces would be very useful, but you could do it with a single port, a managed switch and VLANS.
4. Yes you can set this up to do everything a wireless router could - A lot of the better wireless routers are actually imbedded Linux boxes.  (Case in point DD-WRT based systems).

There is no 1 place to look as you need to get up to speed with all the subsystems.  Things to google include

- Linux Routing IPTables usage  (You will need this for port forwarding
  and firewalling.
- Research Linux masquerading)
- Bridging  (you may not need this)
- SAMBA (for Windows Fileserver)
- DHCP and DNS - dhcpd, bind
  (probably overkill) and dnsmasq are common solutions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Superuser. I shall continue my search there. It's good to know this is possible. Thanks for the start.